# Passing `Func<Task>` to a method - any differences between calling func vs. lambda vs. async/await lambda?

Tags: c#, async-await

Let's consider methods:

```
public static void FireAsyncAndForget(Func<Task> func)
{
    JoinableTaskFactory.RunAsync(func).FileAndForget();
}

async Task DoAsync()
{
    await SomeOtherMethodAsync();
}
```

Is there any difference in terms of how the code is executed between the 3 examples below?

1. `FireAsyncAndForget(DoAsync);`
2. `FireAsyncAndForget(() => DoAsync());`
3. `FireAsyncAndForget(async () => await DoAsync());`

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "any difference". Let's find out. Here are three "to do" lists:  (1) "make a sandwich", (2) "make a todo list that says 'make a sandwich' and then do what's on that list", (3) "make a  todo list that says 'make a todo list that says (make a sandwich) then do what's on that list' then do what's on that list".  **Is there any difference in terms of how those to-do lists are executed?** They all result in a sandwich. If the answer is yes, then the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: @EricLippert One more layer of delegation is missing in the case that  your name happens to be Sandwich and are too busy gambling at the bar or out for the weekend on a fishing party, where you would  instead "give order to make sandwich and have it brought to me".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, all three of these will seemingly execute identically, though there is a subtle difference.

Option 1 will execute DoAsync directly, while the other two are calling a function that itself calls DoAsync. This will create an extra entry on your stack. Same logic applies to option 3 compared to 2, there is an extra await call and so (unless the compiler optimizes it away) I would expect it to generate an extra state.

Seeing a notable run time difference between these, though, I would expect to be in the realm of micro-optimizations.